# How to find a set of missing dates in a table from date range query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gaps-and-islands, rails-postgresql

There are some stackoverflow posts related to my question but not all that similar.

I would like an efficient and somewhat elegant(if possible) solution as to get an array of missing dates after comparing a user specified date range to the summary table in postgresql. One method I know of is to lay the range out into a list of dates and then compare individually to all the dates by querying EXIST or if result == nil?/empty?, etc. But if user was to do a large range, this could be resource consuming and slow.

Is there any methods beside the ones that are currently listed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to sort the dates. In ruby this is as simple as

```
sorted_dates = dates.sort
```

If you know the dates are sorted, then just start with the first date and increment by one as you iterate through your date range. If the next date in your array is not the date you expected, add the missing date to your missing_dates array, and continue incrementing until you reach the date included.

This code might look like the following:

```
def find_missing_dates(sorted_dates)
  current_date = sorted_dates[0]
  missing_dates = Set.new
  sorted_dates.each do |date|
    while current_date != date
      missing_dates << current_date
      current_date += 1.day
    end
    current_date += 1.day
  end
end
```

This is O(N) for average case, so to get it more efficient, we could split in half and recurse.

```
def dates_between(lower, upper)
  (lower..upper).to_a - [lower,upper]
end

def find_missing_dates(sorted_dates, missing_dates = Set.new)
    min_date = sorted_dates[0]
    max_date = sorted_dates[-1]
    if (min_date - max_date).to_i == (sorted_dates.count - 1)
      missing_dates
    else
      middle_date_lower = sorted_dates[sorted_dates.count / 2 - 1]
      middle_date_upper = sorted_dates[sorted_dates.count / 2]
      unless (middle_date_upper - middle_date_lower) == 1
        missing_dates.merge(dates_between(middle_date_lower, middle_date_upper))
      end
      find_missing_dates(sorted_dates[0..(sorted_dates.count/2 - 1)], missing_dates).merge(find_missing_dates(sorted_dates[(sorted_dates.count/2)..-1]))
    end
end

find_missing_dates(sorted_dates)
```

This is still worst case O(N), but average case is O(log N)